The "hash-based-cryptography" tag same as the "hash-signature"?
I accidentally created and added info for the "hash-based-cryptography" tag, which I didn't know there had already been a "hash-signature" tag. 
I suppose they should be merged, given there's unlikely a public-key encryption or key encapsulation scheme based on cryptographic hash functions. 

hash-based-cryptography is now a synomyn of hash-signature.
